# Automatically refresh browser on save

Tags: google-chrome, refresh, atom-editor, local, autosave

Is there a way to have the chrome browser automatically refresh whenever the file it's accessing changes? I want to run my files locally (not with a server). I'm using atom. I've so far found "browser-refresh-on-save" as an atom package but it does not work on Windows 32, which is what I'm using. All other solutions I've found require me to be running a server.

Comment: There are several third-party packages supporting browsersync or livereload. However, StackOverflow isn't a platform for software recommendations, but for programming problems – so please take this elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for a software recommendation. I'm open to programming something myself if someone suggested it a worthy course of action. Furthermore, I asked for a solution without the need for a server. Both browsersync and livereload require a server.